# Error handling between modules

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to ensure that my error trapping is working correctly but not sure I understand the proper procedure for handling an error that was found in another module.

If I had in module1

```
Sub test()
. . . . 'macro code Part1

SAtext = SAdata(SApage, "A")

. . . . . 'macro code part2

my5Error:
ASSoffice = Empty
prv1 = Empty
TNT = Empty
End sub
```

I would want the macro code part1 to run and call the SAdata function.  When the function runs, I want it to run the function code part1 and then check if err.number = 5 will occur.  If it doesn't then the error handling is reset, but if it does I want it to skip the 'function code part2' section and run the code at myBlank:  This part seems to work okay.

```
Function SAdata(SApage, "A")
. . . . Function code part1

On Error Resume Next
    myresponse = Mid(xmlHTTP.responseText, InStr(1, xmlHTTP.responseText, "Ref No.", vbTextCompare), Len(xmlHTTP.responseText))
    If Err.Number = 5 Then GoTo myBlank
    On Error GoTo 0

. . . . . function code part2
myBlank:
Set xmlHTTP = Nothing
Set oDoc = Nothing
Set objData = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

After the error handling is complete for the function, how would I identify that an error had occurred in the function and to skip the 'macro code part2' section?

Comment: have a local boolean variable you pass out as the return of the function (i.e. pass an array back with (0) as your original and (1) as your boolean) set to True if err.number 5? Pass that back to SAData and test If ... ? Or use a global variable and set that

Answer (score 0):

Something like this if using global

```
Option Explicit
Public error5 As Boolean

Sub test()
    '. . . . 'macro code Part1

    SAtext = SAdata(SApage, "A")

    If error5 Then

        '. . . . . 'macro code part2
    End If

    '....
End Sub

Public Function SAdata(SApage , "A" )
    '. . . . Function code part1

    On Error Resume Next
    myresponse = Mid(xmlHTTP.responseText, InStr(1, xmlHTTP.responseText, "Ref No.", vbTextCompare), Len(xmlHTTP.responseText))

    If Err.Number = 5 Then GoTo myBlank

    On Error GoTo 0


    '. . . . . function code part2

    Exit Function

myBlank:
    error5 = True
    Set xmlHTTP = Nothing
    Set oDoc = Nothing
    Set objData = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Here is a rough and ready test case

```
Option Explicit
Public error5 As Boolean


Sub test()
    '. . . . 'macro code Part1
    Dim SAPage As Variant
    Dim SAtext As String

    SAPage = 1

    SAtext = SAdata(SAPage, "A")

    If error5 Then
       '. . . . . 'macro code part2
       Debug.Print "The was a runtime error: " & error5

    Else
      Debug.Print "No show"
    End If

    '....
End Sub

Public Function SAdata(ByVal SAPage As Variant, Optional ByVal myString As String = "A") As String
    Dim myresponse As String
    Dim xmlHTTP As Object
    Dim oDoc As Object
    Dim objData As Object

    '. . . . Function code part1

    On Error Resume Next
    myresponse = Mid(vbNullString, Len(vbNullString) - 1)

    If Err.Number = 5 Then GoTo myBlank

    On Error GoTo 0


    '. . . . . function code part2

   Exit Function

myBlank:
    error5 = True
    Set xmlHTTP = Nothing
    Set oDoc = Nothing
    Set objData = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: Did you try these answers?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to rethrow an error instead of using a global flag.  Then in the calling method simply add error handling.  In the following code, I added the necessary code including `Exit Sub`:

```
Sub test()
   'macro code Part1

   On Error GoTo my5Error
   SAtext = SAdata(SApage, "A")
   On Error GoTo 0

   'macro code part2

   Exit Sub

my5Error:
   ASSoffice = Empty
   prv1 = Empty
   TNT = Empty
   On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

In the following code, don't forget to include the `Exit Function` statement, and then add the `Err.Raise` at the end.

```
Function SAdata(SApage, SALetter)
   'Function code part1

   On Error Resume Next
   myresponse = Mid(xmlHTTP.responseText, InStr(1, xmlHTTP.responseText, "Ref No.", vbTextCompare), Len(xmlHTTP.responseText))
   If Err.Number = 5 Then GoTo myBlank
   On Error GoTo 0

   'function code part2

   Exit Function

myBlank:
   Set xmlHTTP = Nothing
   Set oDoc = Nothing
   Set objData = Nothing
   On Error GoTo 0
   Err.Raise vbObjectError + 513, "SAdata", "My error"
End Function
```